# How do I detect if a string is a path of any kind?

Tags: php

This might be an easy answer. I'm using DOMdocument to traverse html documents and collect attribute names and values. I'm collecting both these values as generic terms, but I'd like to catch any values that are paths. Regardless of them being relative or absolute, and what the attribute name is e.g. src, href etc.

Is there a way I can do an if test

i.e.

```
if ($attrValue is path){
do something
}
```

Comment: It's a very limited set of attributes that store paths. Why not just access them directly instead of guessing?

Comment: that was my first approach, but it's only really a limited set of attributes that *only* store paths. For example <meta content= sometimes includes paths but not always. I'm capturing all attribute values, so I then want to sort through them and find the ones that are paths.

Comment: "sometimes includes paths but not always" --- `<meta name="description" content="Awesome Description Here">` --- could you say if the `content` attribute is a path in this particular case?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Since a meta tag can look like your example and also like this:
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.website.com/images/icon.png" />

I need to be able to gather both these attribute values and then sort the regular strings from the ones that are paths to *something*

Comment: you said: "Regardless of them being relative or absolute". So I gave you an example: `<meta name="description" content="Awesome Description Here">`. And asked if you think `content` attribute here is a "path of any kind" or not. What do you think?

Comment: it's not a path of any kind...

Comment: are you sure? I see a relative path, which consists of a file name without extension. So **it is** a path, isn't it?

Comment: Cool, fair point. So let's say that I'm only interested in relative or absolute paths that point to something that has an extension (which may or may not have trailing query strings or hash references)

Comment: `<meta name="description" content="Awesome Description Here. It is still weird though">` --- like this? It's something that looks like a filename with an extension.

Comment: OK, I get your point. So are you saying that you see no possible way to find *all* paths in an array of strings, even if it means that a few strings resembling a path structure might validate and get through?

Comment: I mean - it depends on how cool are you with having false positive and false negative results. I would: 1) get the data from attributes that are assumed to be a valid paths (`src`, `href`, etc) as is 2) Iterate over all other attributes using something like http://php.net/parse_url And I would definitely split 1 and 2 results, the 1st ones quality is much better

Comment: "So are you saying that you see no possible way to find all paths in an array of strings" --- it is possible, as soon as you give a "path" term definition that suits your current task (and that won't hurt you much in case of some real paths were missed while some garbage was returned)

Comment: Great, that's really helpful. I'll have a bucket for certain attribute types I know are paths and others which may include false positives. I'll test against a standard filename.extension regex pattern to sort the ambiguous ones.

Answer (score 1):

Using a [regular expression](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
function isPath($str) {
    return preg_match('#^(\w+/){1,2}\w+\.\w+$#',$str);
}

if(ispath($attrValue)) {
    // it's a path
}
```

Comment: This makes sense to me. It didnt catch all the paths on my first test,but that just means I need to find a better regex pattern.

Comment: "better regex pattern" --- there is no such.

Comment: Any suggestions to a different approach?

Comment: @user2805520: see comments